Python script performs other actions defined from library fine, but won't perform an action that writes predefined email
I have a script using pyautogui that launches a website from a predefined library depending on elements of the filename. It then activates another library to engage a set of actions to tab across the site and enter inputs.
They all work fine except "enter email". I've even tried to have it write out each character individually and introduce a time.sleep, but nothing has worked even a solitary time.
This is the relevant code:
email = "info@oakpointpartners.com"

state_actions_category_1 = {
    "NV": ["5 tabs", "input CID", "tab", "input CID again", "tab", "enter email", "tab", "enter email", "tab", "enter", "wait 2 seconds", "enter filename with extension", "enter", "wait 2 seconds", "2 tabs", "1 downkey", "5 tabs", "spacebar", "tab", "enter"],
}

def perform_actions(driver, state, cid, actions, filename, is_test_file=False):

    # Replace placeholders in actions with actual values
    actions = [
        action.replace("enter email", f"enter '{email}'")
               .replace("input CID", f"input '{cid}'")
               .replace("enter filename with extension", f"enter '{filename}.pdf'")
               .replace("enter filename being processed", f"enter '{filename}'")
        for action in actions
    ]
    
    # Log actions being executed for test files
    if is_test_file:
        log_message(f"Executing actions for state {state}: {actions}", to_console=True)

    # Open the corresponding website or mailing address
    if state in state_urls:
        url = state_urls[state]
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)  # Wait for the page to load
        print(f"Performing actions for state: {state}, CID: {cid} (Processing file: {filename})")
    
    for action in actions:
        if "tabs" in action:
            pyautogui.press('tab', presses=int(action.split()[1]))
        elif "downkey" in action:
            pyautogui.press('down', presses=int(action.split()[1]))
        elif "spacebar" in action:
            pyautogui.press('space')
        elif "enter" in action:
            pyautogui.press('enter')
        elif "input CID" in action:
            pyautogui.write(cid)
        elif "wait" in action:
            time.sleep(int(action.split()[1]))
        elif "enter email" in action:
            # Loop through each character of the email and type it individually
            for char in email:
                pyautogui.write(char)  # Type the individual character
                time.sleep(0.1)  # Add a slight delay to simulate human typing speed
            pyautogui.press('tab')  # Press 'tab' after typing the email
        elif "enter filename being processed" in action:
            # Input the filename without .pdf extension
            pyautogui.write(filename)
            time.sleep(0.1)  # Brief delay after typing
        elif "enter filename with extension" in action:
            # Input the filename with .pdf extension
            filename_with_extension = append_pdf_extension(filename)
            pyautogui.write(filename_with_extension)
            time.sleep(0.2)  # 1/5 second delay after typing

I've run it through ChatGPT and CoPilot. Neither have been able to offer a solution that has caused the email address to be output once. Thanks in advance for any insight.
Tried introducing time.sleep and having the script output individual characters instead of the full text.

action.replace("enter email", f"enter '{email}'") This code replaces the action text "enter email" with different text.  So later when you do elif "enter email" in action: that condition is never true, because that text is no longer in the action.

You say They all work fine except "enter email", but I would expect the "enter filename being processed" and "enter filename with extension" cases to have the same problem that I mentioned above.  Do those cases work correctly?

Furthermore, elif "enter" in action: will match all of "enter email", "enter filename being processed" and "enter filename with extension", preventing those respective handlers from running even if you fixed the issue above.

What confuses me so much is that "enter filename being processed" and "enter filename with extension" both work correctly. I tried changing the actions to def perform_actions(driver, state, cid, actions, filename, email, is_test_file=False):', added action .replace("email", email), and changed "enter email" to <elif "email" in action:, and yet it still doesn't work.

As @blhsing commented, the code checks for "enter" before it checks for the longer strings "enter email", "enter filename being processed", etc.  So there's no way the longer strings would ever be recognized.  If they are, then your real code must be different from what you have shown here.
